# pygame not closing and going back to console (python)

Tags: python, pygame

I'm using pygame raspberry pi and adafruit tft screen to display content.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from subprocess import *
from  numpy import genfromtxt
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import os
import time
from time import strftime
#from pygame.locals import*
#from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import datetime

def run_cmd(cmd):
      """Used to run Linux commands"""
      p = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
      output = p.communicate()[0]
      return output

def displayText(text, size, line, color, clearScreen):

    """Used to display text to the screen. displayText is only configured to display 
    two lines on the TFT. Only clear screen when writing the first line"""
    if clearScreen:
        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    font = pygame.font.Font(None, size)
    text = font.render(text, 0, color)
    textRotated = pygame.transform.rotate(text, -90)
    textpos = textRotated.get_rect()
    textpos.centery = 80   
    if line == 1:
        textpos.centerx = 90
        screen.blit(textRotated,textpos)
    elif line == 2:
        textpos.centerx = 40
        screen.blit(textRotated,textpos)


def displayTime():
    """Used to display date and time on the TFT"""
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, 50)
    now=time.localtime()

    for setting in [("%H:%M:%S",60),("%d  %b",10)] :
         timeformat,dim=setting
         currentTimeLine = strftime(timeformat, now)
         text = font.render(currentTimeLine, 0, (0,250,150))
         Surf = pygame.transform.rotate(text, -90)
         screen.blit(Surf,(dim,20))

def main():
    global ax,fig,screen
    global firstTime,lines
    global TwentyFourHours,TwelveHours,OneWeek
    global dataFile

    size = width, height = 128, 160
    TFTxSize = 2.28
    TFTySize = 1.63
    TwentyFourHours = 288
    TwelveHours = 144
    OneWeek = 2016
    firstTime = True      #Used to work out if a function has already been run
    whatToDisplay = 1     #What do display on screen
    rotate = 0            #Used when automatically rotating the display.
    startTime = time.time()   #Used to work out how much time has passed when rotating.

  #Set the framebuffer device to be the TFT
    os.environ["SDL_FBDEV"] = "/dev/fb1"

  #Setup pygame display
    pygame.init()
    pygame.mouse.set_visible(0)
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

    try:
        while True:
                time.sleep(.5)
                firstTime = True      #If button pressed, set this to True
                if whatToDisplay == 1:    #Display time
                    displayTime()
                elif whatToDisplay == 2:  #Display last temperature recorded.
                    displayText('Current Temp', True )
                elif  whatToDisplay == 3: #Rotate display
                    elapsedTime = time.time() - startTime
        #Write to TFT
                pygame.display.flip()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Pressing ^C does not close the screen display and doesn't return to console.
I have to restart the pi, which is quite painful to test stuff out.
The display is fine and I will be resolving any other issues when I can close it properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`KeyboardInterrupt` won't be launched if keys are handled by pygame. Here's how you can detect the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> event.

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if (event.type == pygame.KEYUP and event.key == pygame.K_c and 
            event.mod & pygame.KMOD_CTRL):
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```

:)

Comment: Thank you so much. Works a charm. I have marked you as a correct answer but I cannot yet give public upvotes.